# Networking: SNMP in the ADV Environment in C#

Tags: python, ftp

I am having a hard time trying to implement the FTP client in python that does the following:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work for downloading a file. [The official Python documentation for ftplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) shows that there are a number of commands to do just what you need. In particular:

```
ftplib.cwd() # change working directory
ftplib.rmd() # remove directory
```

Also use `ftplib.dir()` to get a listing of the files and folders in a directory.

I can only assume this is a homework assignment so I won't spell out the entire solution but you have enough to do it now.

Comment: no, this is not a home work question. But I will try my best first and will update you the solution quickly later.

Comment: May I ask why you're using python? It sounds like you would much prefer to use C.

Comment: We don't need to python. We could use C. Do  you recommend any better alternative (library)? In fact, C would be better for me because I am not familiar with python.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't recommend anything for C. I don't use C very much.